# Send textarea content to javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Ok so I got a textarea and a link (which works as a button) and what I am trying to do is that when I click on the link, it sends the content from the textarea to a javascript function.
Something like this...:

```
<textarea name="text" placeholder="Type your text here!"></textarea>
<a href="" onclick="myFunction(<!-- sends the value of the textarea that the user enters and then sends it to myFunction -->); return false;">Send!</a>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just assign an `id` to your textarea, and use `document.getElementById`:

```
<textarea name="text" placeholder="Type your text here!" id="myTextarea"></textarea>
<a href="" onclick="myFunction(document.getElementById('myTextarea').value); return false;">Send!</a>
```

---

Alternatively, you could instead change your `myFunction` function, to make it define the value inside the function:

**JS:**

```
function myFunction() {
    var value = document.getElementById('myTextarea').value;
    //rest of the code
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<textarea name="text" placeholder="Type your text here!" id="myTextarea"></textarea>
<a href="" onclick="myFunction(); return false;">Send!</a>
```

---

And if you're using jQuery, which it does look like you do, you could change the `document.getElementById('myTextarea').value` to `$('#myTextarea').val();` to get the following:

**JS:**

```
function myFunction() {
    var value = $('#myTextarea').val();
    //rest of the code
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<textarea name="text" placeholder="Type your text here!" id="myTextarea"></textarea>
<a href="" onclick="myFunction(); return false;">Send!</a>
```

Comment: Thanks! Adding a id and document.getelementbyid worked exactly like i wanted it!

Answer (score 1):

you can do simply like this to achieve it, just call function and do all work in that function:

```
<a href="" onclick="myFunction();">Send</a>
```

Jquery code:

```
function myFunction()
{
    var text = $('textarea[name="text"]').val();

    // use text here

    return false;
}
```